# ag-grid vs slick-grid vs angular-grid which is better?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, angular-ui-grid, slickgrid, ag-grid

Recently we thought to change our current grid tool. Currently we're using kendo-ui for grid and all. After searching we came with 3 results. But, still we're not sure which is better and why in future run.

While using kendo we missed having control over it. It would be a great if any one can help us out on choosing right grid with **angularjs**.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Disclosure: I'm the founder and CEO of ag-Grid.

First, some clarification on the question, ag-Grid used to be called angular-grid, however I presume you meant angular-ui-grid (or simply ui-grid), so allow me to answer ag-grid vs slick-grid vs ui-grid. The answer is ag-Grid.

For reference, these are the sites: [ag-Grid](http://www.ag-grid.com), [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/), [slick-grid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)

All grids are popular and widely used, each with a community of users.

To give a full comparison is outside the context of a Stackoverflow response, however feedback from the community says ag-Grid is better for the following reasons:

1. ui-Grid only works in AngularJS 1.x. ag-Grid supports Angular 1 and 2, React and even native Javascript (no-Framework). So if using ui-Grid, you have only one option for your framework, that's AngularJS 1. Slickgrid is native Javascript (uses JQuery) so will work outside any framework also.
2. Documentation for ag-Grid is excellent.
3. For enterprise features (grouping, filtering, custom cell rendering, pinning) ag-Grid again wins. The grouping and aggregation feature of ag-Grid is not matched by the others. Slickgrid doesn't have pinning, which was a blocker for me. Only ag-Grid has Excel like filtering.
4. slickgrid is no longer maintained by the founder (according to his website).
5. ag-Grid is written using pure Javascript, it does not have any libraries as dependencies. ui-grid depends on Angular. Slickgrid depends on JQuery.
6. Performance wise, SlickGrid and ag-Grid are on par. However ui-grid performs poorly on large datasets.
7. Source code wise, the code inside ag-Grid is very well laid out, so when you need to understand how something works, it's easy to debug in through the code.
8. Size-wize, ag-Grid is larger than much of the competition.  Circa 1-Aug-2018, the CDN download for ag-grid is [783978 bytes minified..that doesn't include stylesheets](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1459).  This may be a deal-breaker for some people.
9. And lastly, if ui-grid or slickgrid were up to my standards, I wouldn't have needed to write ag-Grid!

Comment: FYI, I am now the main maintainer of SlickGrid, there's an up-to-date repo at https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid

Comment: @niall what is your opinion on angular2 material table or cdk table

Comment: @SumitKhanduri i have not used either so cannot speak from experience. however both seem very limited in their feature set going from what's on their websites.

Comment: @NiallCrosby We are planning to shift to ag-grid will it be the right choice or should we stick to angular2 material table. Kindly guide us

Comment: @SumitKhanduri ag-Grid has more features that material table. compare the features of both and then make your own decision. i've never used material table (due to lack of features) so i can't offer advice beyond feature comparison.

Comment: @NiallCrosby you say that documentation is excellent but I have been unable to find any documentation specific to Angular 2+. All code examples are in JavaScript - no TypeScript. I have to make a decision on how to handle the lack of ui-grid in Angular 2+ and the lack of TypeScript in the documentation gives the impression that Angular 2+ is not a priority in ag-grid, and that some of the documentation may not be applicable in Angular 2+. For example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#gsc.tab=0 shows direct DOM interaction which is not very Angular.

Comment: @tomfumb please look at the documentation closer. most of the examples allow you to select from plain JS / React / Angular 2. for items such as cell renderer, there are sections devoted to angular 2 eg https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#ng2CellRendering

Comment: In the future, please be sure to include your affiliation with products you're discussing or recommending.

Comment: agGrid has very nice ergonomics, BUT I think it would be forthcoming of you to mention the [size of the JS payload](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1459) in your post. I just spent hours of time trying to learn it...only to be bitten by finding the [CDN download file](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1459) is 783978 bytes **minified**..that doesn't include stylesheets.  It's a dealbreaker for what I'm doing, and I'm clearly not alone in that. :-/  Please update this post to mention it, and what you're doing to address it.

Comment: Any documentation or references for claim #6, that ag-Grid and Slickgrid performance is on par? That's not the case according to this test: http://www.crankuptheamps.com/blog/posts/2017/10/05/grid-comparison/

Comment: agGrid community is fantastic and comes with the MIT license.  Read the license carefully before buying Enterprise.  No reduced price updates, no maintenance options - pay the full price every year.  Every JS developer must be licensed even if not doing agGrid work.  Every public facing website requires SaaS license.  https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-enterprise/blob/master/LICENSE.md

Comment: Agreed with @HostileFork

Comment: Release some features to mit, some of that is very basic. Im not going to pay 750USD for clipboard, filtering and grouping, and for only single app? *you crazy*. Now Im looking for alternates.

Comment: Trust me, those extra kb's totally worth it!! There few things which only ag-grid handles exceptionally, one example is scroll-sync when you need few pinned column and table is bit complex, things can go out of sync with multigrid and with two list or list + grid and scrollsync (react-virtualized) it will be laggy very laggy! Though react-virtualized rocks with single table and is small

Comment: Documentation for ag-Grid is NOT excellent and the support with TypeScript typings is really BAD. One can see that it's coming from JavaScript and has nothing to do with modern Angular design. RxJS is not supported, only 1999-like callback functions. I'm disappointed.

Comment: Pls help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018177/ag-grid-community-infinite-row-model-for-server-side-pagination-community-free/65040658#65040658

Comment: SlickGrid is now using browser native code and no longer requires jQuery in SlickGrid 4.0 (https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid)

Answer (score 31):

I was looking around and found the best answer here : http://jspreadsheets.com.

All popular grid tools in one place, with demos and features and popularity indicators right there.

To make this a StackOverflow accepted answer, the comparison lists, in decreasing order of github stars:

- Handsontable, handsontable.com
- SlickGrid
- Clusterize.js
- ui-grid , ui-grid.info
- DataTables, datatables.net
- ng-table, ng-table.com
- jqGrid
- FancyGrid
- BackGrid.js, backgridjs.com
- Recline.js
- ag-grid, ag-grid.com
- Multiple others

All of these are usable within an Angular app, some more 'native' than others. Which one is 'better' depends on what you want to accomplish, and level of effort going into it.

Comment: Jspreadsheets.com is not a good reference as GitHub stars are subjective to the age of the project. Eg ag-Grid is very new, so will take time to build up its stars. popularity also doesn't suggest quality, GitHub stars are equivalent to X factor votes!

Comment: It doesnt need to be a reference for evaluating 'quality', as this is subjective for project needs anyway. It is a good reference for listing the existing solutions that are widely used, and immediately giving an overview of capabilities and features offered.

Comment: That site looks like it is written by the people who make Handsontable (my favourite anyway). However, it doesn't mention OpenFin Hypergrid which you should keep an eye on  http://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid-polymer-demo/components/fin-hypergrid/demo.html

Answer (score -4):

I like  [Jeet grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jeet)

with [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/)

Stylus makes no attempt to be CSS syntax compliant and so is more powerful than SCSS

Comment: Jeet is a grid systems (layout), this question is about Data Grids