# Datatable vs Angular UI Grid vs Slick Grid vs Ag-Grid

Tags: datatables

I saw there are several flavours of grid. People recommends to use Angular UI Grid when the records are huge instead of Datatables.

I think the data table is populating each row 1 by 1 and causing the performance issue.

Is it not possible to fix the Data table performance issue similar to other grids?

How the angular UI grid works internally or other grids handles differently then the Data tables?

Thanks.

Comment: You say angular, but from the components you've mentioned, it appears you're using AngularJs(v1.x). If that is the case, please edit the question and add relevant tags so people can find your question. Is you're talking about Angular(v2.x or above) we have a good experience we can share.

Comment: It's Angular v2.x and not v1.x

Comment: For instance, Angular UI Grid is Angular 1.x [See here](http://ui-grid.info/)

Comment: I'm a handsontable man myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, these are the sites:[ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/),[ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/),[slick-grid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)

we have [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747904/ag-grid-vs-slick-grid-vs-angular-grid-which-is-better)

and

DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery

DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive enhancement, and will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML table.

[Data Table](https://datatables.net/)

and

[JavaScript Open-Source Spreadsheets and Data Grids](https://jspreadsheets.com/)

Comment: I am not asking about which one is better but trying to understand how others are better than Datatables and what datatable is missing which others has fixed it. Is it something can be fixed or not doable or design restriction ?